# proxy main domain to a subdomain

Tags: apache-2.2, nginx, web-server

I want to redirect a main domain to a subdomain for example **www.abc.com** to **xyz.test.com**. Whenever i type **www.abc.com** it should be redirect to **xyz.test.com**. Both domain are hosted on same server.

Subdomain **xyz.test.com** is not a virtual host of web server (i.e. apache & nginx) it is code generated website and you can directly access it via **http://xyz.test.com**. I'm using apache and nginx both so whatever best fit i will use. Any help would be appreciated.

Thank You :)

Answer (score 0):

I have resolved this by changing apache virtual host config to following,

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerName  www.abc.com
        ProxyPass / http://xyz.test.com/
        ProxyPassReverse / http://xyz.test.com/
</VirtualHost>
```

now when i open **www.abc.com** it shows webpage from **xyz.test.com**